# Fiware: How to create lazy attributes through IDAS UltraLight

Tags: agent, fiware

I'm using the IoT Agent Ultra-Light module to communicate with the Orion context broker. I can create services and devices and I have checked that the observations reach the context broker too.

```
curl -X POST XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090/iot/services \
-i  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: sanitysrv " \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: / sanitysspath " \
-d '{"services": [{"apikey": "", "cbroker": "http://127.0.0.1:1026", "entity_type": "Dispositivo_tmp", "resource": "/iot/d"}]}'


curl -X POST XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090/iot/devices \
-i  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: sanitysrv" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /sanitysspath" \
-d '{"devices":[{"device_id":"CE_BDM_3","protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltraLight", "commands": [], "attributes": [{"type":"int","name":"temperature","object_id":"t"}]}]}'
```

My problem is that I don´t know how to register a device that contains lazy attributes, and I haven´t found any documentation with related examples. The examples from other IoT Agents that I have tried are not working here.

¿How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Lazy attributes are not supported in the UL2.0/MQTT Agent so far but in IoT Agents developed with node.js.

We'll let you know as soon as this feature is available.

Cheers,